# How to get Visual Studio Code to Prompt for opening a folder in a new window

Tags: visual-studio-code

I seem to have messed up my default settings for this feature in Visual Studio Code and now can't figure out how to set it back. I don't want to reset everything to default as I've changed other settings along the way.

**What I want to happen**

When in Visual Studio Code I select `File`=>`Open Recent` and then select a folder I want it to ask me if I want to open this folder in a new window or the same window.

**What's happening**

When in Visual Studio Code I select `File`=>`Open Recent` and then select a folder it opens the new folder in the same window which closes the currently opened folder

Comment: There are `Open Folders in New Window` and `Open Files in New Window` settings.  See if you changed those.  I don't know that you ever get a dialog asking you whether to open a new window or not, but there are three options to choose from.

Comment: Hi @Mark, where are these settings and how do you change them?

Comment: They are in the Gear icon/Settings UI.  Then search for those words.